# sending request to server and getting response

Tags: php, request, response

i have question about sending and getting data from server, i just want to know is it doable  what i want to achieve. So here is the thing:
i have some data that i want to send to server, like some id, name, surname
and i have server with ip 256.257.258.259, server waits for request with values encoded in url, so i can send data to server somehow like this:

```
        $data = array(
            'id'=>'c456ki98765',
            'name'=>'john',
            'surname'=>'smith');
$urlstring = http_build_query($data);

   $url = 'http://256.257.258.259/folder/automatic?'.($urlstring);
```

i have a question there, should i use GET request to send this kind of data?
and would it look something like this?

```
$request = new HttpRequest('url', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
```

and when server gets my data it sends back response - for example json data - 'number' string or 'error' string if id is wrong. And i have another question there, how can i get data that server sends me after i have sent request? 
how can i get that 'number'or 'error'? i hope i have made my question clear

Comment: You should use POST to send data as the URL is limited in length (and also there is REST, on which you might want to read up). In the POST data, you could then use json_decode on the server and then use somethig as simple as 'echo' to reply to the client. Use json_encode to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a POST or a GET request depending on your requirements

Your $request is fine for setting up the request but then you need to send it:

$request->send();

and will need to do something with the response code:

$request->getResponseCode()

Hopefully the below links will come in handy (especially the bottom on in this case):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-data.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php